# ChartJS remove numbers in graph

Tags: javascript, vue.js, charts

I have a chartJS component in Vue, and I am having troubles in removing the numbers shown inside the graph. The graph is shown in the picture below, and if you look closely you see that the value of each point is shown in the graph, at the point.

I have looked for configuration options that enable/disable this feature, however I am not able to find it anywhere. No mention of this feature whatsoever.

[image]

My configuration is:

```js
      plotOptions: {
        responsive: true,
        maintainAspectRatio: false,
        bezierCurve: true,
        tooltips: {
          enabled: false,
        },
        legend: { display: true },
        scales: {
          yAxes: [
            {
              display: true,
              type: "logarithmic",
            },
          ],
        },
      },
```

And the line:

```js
        labels: Array.from(Array(512).keys()),
        datasets: [
          {
            label: "Spectrum",
            fill: false,
            borderColor: "rgba(8, 8, 8, 0.4)",
            backgroundColor: "rgba(8, 8, 8, 0.5)",
            pointBackgroundColor: "rgba(8, 8, 8, 1)",
            data: yval,
          },
        ],
      };
```

So my intended result is: remove the number in the graph around the dots.

Comment: the labels shown in the chart are typically added by a plugin. by just adding the .js library to the page. which .js libraries are included?

Comment: Thank you for this hint. Looking at the plugins used by other components helped to solve this issue. I will answer my question

Answer (score 1):

As it turned out this behavior was caused by an other component that I used in my project. At an other component I used the `chartjs-plugin-datalabels` plugin. I first overlooked this because vue has each component seperated in a .vue file.

The solution:

1. Registed the `chartjs-plugin-datalabels` plugin for the linechart component.
2. Added the following lines to my `plotOptions`:

```js
         plugins: {
            datalabels: {
              display: false,
            }
        },
```

Comment: In my case, i add datalabels in the datasets section and work is fine:

`datalabels: {
          display: false 
 }
`